# Wordpress blank white screen when I try to preview or visit the site?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and I jut installed it today, I created a username and password, am able to login to wordpress and access the dashboard. I made a few changes, installed a theme, created a menu, picked out a header, etc...

When I try to preview the site however, it just shows a blank white screen, anyone know how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem in the past... to solve it I edited the wp-config.php file and activated the debug function... that let wordpress show me what the error was, so I could fix it...

Basically in wp-config.php search for:
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

and replace it with:
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Once your done fixing the error don't forget to change it back...

taken from: [Wordpress Codex - editing wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)